# Axway Tumbleweed Desktop Validator unable to validate certificate?

Tags: security, ssl-certificate, website

Anyone use or know anything about Axway Validation Authority Suite? I am currently googling the heck out of this and not finding an answer. It looks like I will have to read the Administration documents to figure this out (if I can find them).

Here's my problem, I'm using a valid ssl domain certificate on a website. Secure.domain.com from GoDaddy. I know their certificates are kinda cheap, but still.

The problem is with the Tumbleweed Desktop Validator saying that it can't validate the certificate.

This is on my clients network, not mine, so I don't know anything about this Tumbleweed tool.

My guess is that this is something that will need to be taken care of by my clients IT department or whoever manages that tool.

My client thinks it's my problem, something wrong with the certificate, but I can't figure out what could be wrong with it.

Anyone know anything about this Axway software??

Thanks to anyone who reads this and responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.axway.com/products-solutions/email-identity-security/identity-security/va-suite

Validation Authority is a certificate repository.  Your desktop client is just that, a client.

The cert needs to be added by the IT admin of your client.